# How SplPriorityQueue works when priority is not an integer?

Tags: php, spl

I was wondering how `SplPriorityQueue` works when priority is `string` or `int`. Quick example:

```php
    $queue = new \SplPriorityQueue();

    $queue->insert('b', 5);
    $queue->insert('c', 5);
    $queue->insert('d', 1);
    $queue->insert('a', 10);
    $queue->insert('1', 'a');
    $queue->insert('2', 'b');

    print_r($queue);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [5] => a
    [4] => b
    [3] => c
    [2] => d
    [1] => 2
    [0] => 1
)
```

**Question**: why items with `int` priority are listed first (i.e. a b c d)? When priority is `string` (items 1 2), is `b` considered greater than `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is determined by [`SplPriorityQueue::compare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/splpriorityqueue.compare.php). The documentation states about its return value:

> Result of the comparison, positive integer if ***priority1*** is greater
>   than ***priority2***, 0 if they are equal, negative integer otherwise.
>
> > **Note:**
> >
> > Multiple elements with the same priority will get dequeued in no particular order.

Note, that the parameters ***priority1*** and ***priority2*** are declared as `mixed` and there is no mention of converting to int.

This means, the usual rules for `>` apply ([see comparison operator documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)):

- string compared to string: lexical comparison (numerical if both strings are numerical)
- int compared to int: numerical comparison
- string compared to int: string is converted to number, numerical comparison

`(int)'a'` and `(int)'b'` resolves to `0`, this is why these items come last after all numbers.

**These are the relevant comparisons for your example:**

```
php > var_dump(1 > 'a');
bool(true)
php > var_dump(1 > 'b');
bool(true)
php > var_dump('b' > 'a');
bool(true)
```

Comment: Ok, but how compare is used when inserting into the queue? I can't get why 'a' and 'b' get a priority of 0.

Comment: It's used for sorting. The `>` comparison determines the priority *order*. In fact, 'a' and 'b' don't have a priority of 0 but still a priority of 'a' or 'b', which happen to be less than any number because of the comparison results above.