# Unexpected behaviour of SplPriorityQueue in a borderline case

Tags: php, spl

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851726/how-splpriorityqueue-works-when-priority-is-not-an-integer) I asked some time ago.

Basically it's about how dequeuing works in some *borderline* cases. For example:

```
$queue = new SplPriorityQueue();

$queue->insert('foo', 0);
$queue->insert('bar', 0);
$queue->insert('baz', '0');
```

I was expecting exactly the same order `foo` `bar` `baz`:

```
while ($queue->valid()) {
    var_dump($queue->current());
    $queue->next();
}
```

Turns out that is `foo` `baz` `bar`. Can you explain why `baz` goes *before* `bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As foo, bar & baz all have the same priority their order is undefined, so they could come out in any order.  See the note here http://www.php.net/manual/en/splpriorityqueue.compare.php

> Note:
>
> Multiple elements with the same priority will get dequeued in no particular order.

and the top user note on the same page for a suggested solution http://www.php.net/manual/en/splpriorityqueue.compare.php#93999

There is also a blog post on [Matthew Weier O'Phinney's Blog](http://www.mwop.net/blog/253-Taming-SplPriorityQueue.html) which you may find useful.

Comment: Too bad. Is actually possible to write a solution without subclassing?

Comment: I wouldn't think so as that is the internal behaviour of the class.